# After adding a snippet of code a (previously working) anchor stopped working when hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, github, jekyll, anchor

I started building a project from a bootstrap template. Then I added a snippet of code from bootply into the service section. And for some reason the button (anchor) in the first section is not working anymore.

> **Yet, the same anchor I copied into the new section works fine!**

link to website: https://bomengeduld.github.io/debadkamers/

link to index.html: https://github.com/bomengeduld/debadkamers/blob/master/index.html

link to style.css: https://github.com/bomengeduld/debadkamers/blob/master/style.css

### index.html

```
<a href="#" class="button white">OFFERTE</a>
```

### style.css

```
input:focus,
button:focus,
a:focus,
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #000000;
}

.button.white,
.button:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this code in our css.

```
.header-area .v-center{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
```